# comma separation and string truncation

Tags: r, knitr

I've been using a nice [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382512/knitr-hook-to-separate-000s-but-not-for-years) to add comma separation to numbers in knitr reports for some time, but this function seems to have an unintended consequence I never encountered before: it truncates a string with parentheses. I don't understand the use of classes well enough to see why this function affects my string. Here's a simple example.

1) Keep the code as is and the comma separation works (`2,015`) but the string is truncated (`30.2 (10`).

[image]

2) Remove the hook and you see the reverse: no comma separation (`2015`) but the string is ok (`30.2 (10.2)`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<knitr, include=FALSE>>=
  library(knitr)
  nocomma <- function(x){structure(x,class="nocomma")}
  knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
      if(!inherits(x,"nocomma")) return(prettyNum(x, big.mark=","))
      if(inherits(x,"nocomma")) return(x)
      return(x) # default
  })
@

<<ex>>=
x <- paste0("30.2 ", "(", "10.2", ")")
x
# [1] "30.2 (10.2)"
y <- "2015"
@

The `nocomma()` function does a nice job putting a comma in \Sexpr{y}, but \Sexpr{x} gets truncated.

\end{document}
```

What I like about the hook approach is that all inline strings that need 000's separation get commas without me having to manually use a function to set commas in every instance throughout a document. This might not be a great solution, and I'm open to others. But it *was* a pretty functional solution for me...until today, that is, when it broke something else in my document: a string with `(`.

Comment: Isn't this intended to be used as `Sexpr{nocomma(x)}` or something along those lines?

Comment: i added two screenshots of the pdfs generated by approach (1) and (2)

Comment: no, @AnandaMahto the function is set in the hook so you don't have to use inline.

Comment: Why not use `Sexpr(prettyNum(x, big.mark=","))` where needed? Why would you pass `prettyNum("30.2 (10.2)", big.mark=",")`? Looking for trouble. Try using `prettyNum` before `paste`

Comment: @AaronKatch i need something that does not need to be set each time. until this truncation problem, i've never had an issue with this hook.

Comment: @EricGreen well, it looks like `prettyNum("30.2 (10.2)", big.mark=",")` doesn't work as expected. Gives: `"30.2 (10"`

Comment: @AaronKatch yes, I think that's the essence of my question. the hook solves my problem by inserting a comma any time there is an inline string that needs 000s separation, but it creates this new problem of truncating the string with `(` that I need to report in a table. this is a simplified example, but it reproduces my problem.

Comment: Maybe make it so the first thing the hook does is test to see if something is coercible to a numeric - and if not leave it as-is. `if(is.na(as.numeric(x))) return(x)`. Then it will leave strings untouched if they don't seem like a simple number. (Might need to wrap the `as.numeric()` in `suppressWarnings()`.)

Comment: Or you could have it leave strings untouched entirely - `if(is.character(x)) return(x)`, then it would insert a comma in `2015`, but wouldn't in `"2015"`. This is probably the way I would want it, but in your example you pass `"2015"` in as a string and want a comma, so it would require adjustments on your end.

Comment: @Gregor `if(is.na(as.numeric(x))) return(x)` does the trick: it adds a comma to `2,015` and prints `30.2 (10.2)` without truncation. and doesn't appear to break anything else. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using the function as intended. If you look [at the answer to the question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26382883/903061), it comes with two utility functions:

```
comma <- function(x){structure(x,class="comma")}
nocomma <- function(x){structure(x,class="nocomma")}
```

And a slightly different function definition:

```
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
      if(inherits(x,"comma")) return(prettyNum(x, big.mark=","))
      if(inherits(x,"nocomma")) return(x)
      return(x) # default
    })
```

With the intended use case of `comma("2015")` or `nocomma(paste0("30.2 ", "(", "10.2", ")"))`.

The version you have has been modified to *always* attempt to put in a comma unless `nocomma()` is used explicitly. You write:

> The `nocomma()` function does a nice job putting a comma in `\Sexpr{y}`, but `\Sexpr{x}` gets truncated.

Actually, the `nocomma()` function does nothing in your example because you never use it. You could use it with---as the name suggests, to **prevent** commas---like this:

> A comma is added in `\Sexpr{y}` automatically, but using `nocomma()` adds no commas: `\Sexpr{nocomma(x)}`.

If you're looking for a more automatic solution, something that doesn't require you to specify `nocomma()` whenever you *don't* want modification, you can try to make the function guess a little better (like I suggested in my comment):

```
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
      if(is.na(as.numeric(x))) return(x)
      if(!inherits(x,"nocomma")) return(prettyNum(x, big.mark=","))
      return(x) # default
  })
```

This will attempt to coerce the input to numeric. If it doesn't get an `NA`, then it will try to put a comma in it, otherwise it will leave it untouched. Personally, I would prefer to have it only modify numerics and not touch characters:

```
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
      if(!(is.numeric(x)) return(x)
      if(!inherits(x,"nocomma")) return(prettyNum(x, big.mark=","))
      return(x) # default
  })
```

This version will only attempt to modify straight-up numerics, so `2015` will get a comma; `"2015"` and `nocomma(2015)` would not get commas.